# Laravel: Add custom data to resource

Tags: laravel

First I get the translator by his id using this line of code

`$translator = Translator::where('id', $translator_id)->first();`

Then I send a notification to him by this code:

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'key=myKey',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ])->post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', [
            "notification" => [
                "title" => "title",
                "body" => "body",
            ],
            "data" => [
                "title" => "title",
                "body" => "body",
            ],
            "to" => $token,
        ]);
```

Everything works fine but my problem is that when I return the `TranslatorResource` I want to add the notification response to it, so I do this in my controller

```
$resource = new TranslatorResource($translator);
        $resource->notif = $response;
        return $resource;
```

And in `TranslatorResource` I have this code:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'phone' => $this->phone,
            'cv' => $this->cv,
            'specialization' => $this->specialization,
            'tr_languages' => $this->tr_languages,
            'all_languages' => $this->all_languages,
            'isVerified' => $this->isVerified == 0 ? false : true,
            'isActive' => $this->isActive == 0 ? false : true,
            'completed_orders' => $this->completed_orders,
            'canceled_orders' => $this->canceled_orders,
            'rejected_orders' => $this->rejected_orders,
            'current_orders' => $this->current_orders,
            'isTranslator' => true,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
```

But I only get the data specified in the resource, the `notif` key isn't added, anyone know how to add this data to my resource when I return it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `additional` method provided by laravel.

```
return (new TranslatorResource($translator))->additional(['notif ' => $response]);
```

Reference: [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

You can look for the section `Adding Meta Data When Constructing Resources`.